# Personals tree, add break

Tags: php, html, css, laravel

I have a personals tree, like this.

[image]

But I need to break down multiple photo listing into set of `four` like as

[image]

```
<li>
    <div class="image">
        <img src="{{$node->picture}}" class="img-rounded"><br>
        <p>{{$node->name}}</p>
    </div>
    @if($node->children()->count() > 0)
        <ul>
            @foreach($node->children as $personal)
                @include('personal.display', ['node' => $personal])
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    @endif
</li>
```

I used this `CSS` from `codepen io Pestov pen BLpgm`
And tree implementation is used using `Github etrepat baum`

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do that is to use [`take()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-take) method:

```
@foreach($node->children->take(4) as $personal)
```

Another way to do that is to use [the loop variable](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade#the-loop-variable):

```
@foreach($node->children as $personal)
    @if ($loop->iteration <= 4)
        @include('personal.display', ['node' => $personal])
    @endif
@endforeach
```

Comment: I try, but than he take only 4 but i need all staff.

Comment: @ArtursJerjomins it looks like you don't use eager loading. You should always load the data first. Then take() will work with a collection, but not with DB

Comment: Sorry, i understand you. :( When i take only four, than missing two personals. But i need all personals.

Comment: @ArtursJerjomins if you'll [eager load](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) the data first, you will have all children in the collection, but in the `foreach` loop you'll only iterate over 4 first items.

Comment: Sorry. Not my day. Im stupid and english language not the strongest side.
https://paste.laravel.io/EPgrQ

Comment: у меня толька 1 дана базы , может быть по русски получится обьснить ? https://paste.laravel.io/jE4Le